# Make tolower as static

Tags: c, static, inline, misra, tolower

I need to make the standard library function `tolower` static instead of "public' scope.

I am compiling with MISRA C:2004, using IAR Embedded Workbench compiler.  The compiler is declaring `tolower` as inline:

```
  inline
  int tolower(int _C)
  {
    return isupper(_C) ? (_C + ('A' - 'a')) : _C;
  }
```

I am getting the following error from the compiler:

```
Error[Li013]: the symbol "tolower" in RS232_Server.o is public but
is only needed by code in the same module - all declarations at
file scope should be static where possible (MISRA C 2004 Rule 8.10)
```

Here are my suggested solutions:

1. Use `tolower` in another module, in a dummy circumstance, so that it
   is *needed* by more than one module.
2. Implement the functionality without using `tolower`. This is an embedded system.
3. Add a "STATIC" macro, defined as empty by default, but can be
   defined to `static` before the `ctype.h` header file is included.

I'm looking for a solution to the MISRA linker error. I would prefer to make the `tolower` function static only for the RS232_Server translation unit (If I make `tolower` static in the standard header file, it may affect other future projects.)

### Edit 1:

Compiler is IAR Embedded Workbench 6.30 for ARM processor.
I'm using an ARM7TDMI processor in 32-bit mode (not Thumb mode).
The `tolower` function is used with a debug port.

### Edit 2:

I'm also getting the error for `_LocaleC_isupper` and `_LocaleC_tolower`

### Solution:

1. I notified the vendor of the issue according as recommended by Michael Burr.
2. I decided not to rewrite the library routine because of localization
   issues.
3. I implemented a function pointer in the main.c file as suggested by
   gbulmer; however this will be commented incredibly because it should
   be removed after IAR resolves their issue.

Comment: I think we agree it sounds like a bug. But, might there be something else triggering a bug? Can you write a minimal program which uses tolower to see if it goes away? Can you copy ctype.h to a local directory, and throw away everything except the pieces you need? The hope is you'll discover some weirdness either in that file, or an earlier header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who sells the MISRA linker? It seems to have an insane bug.

Can you work around it by taking its address `int (*foo)(int) = tolower;`at file scope?

Edit: My rationale is:

a. that is the stupidest thing I've seen this decade, so it may be a bug, but 

b. pushing it towards an edge case (a symbol having its name exported via a global) might shut it up.

For that to be correct behaviour, i.e. not a bug, it would have to be a MISRA error to include any library function once, like initialise_system_timer, initialise_watchdog_timer, ... , which just hurts my head.

Edit: Another thought. Again based on an assumption that this is an edge-case error.

Theory: Maybe the compiler is doing both the inline, *and* generating an implementation of the function. Then the function is (of course) not being called. So the linker rules are seeing that un-called function.

GNU has options to prevent in-lining. 
Can you do the same for that use of tolower? Does that change the error? You could do a test by

```
#define inline /* nothing */
```

before including ctype.h, then undef the macro.

The other test is to define:

```
#define inline static inline
```

before including ctype.h, which is the version of inline I expect.

EDIT2: 
I think there is a bug which should be reported. I would imagine IAR have a workaround. I'd take their advice.

After a nights sleep, I strongly suspect the problem is `inline int tolower()` rather than `static inline int tolower` or `int tolower`, because it makes most sense. Having a public function which is not called does seem to be the symptoms of a bug in a program.

Even with documentation, all the coding approaches have downsides.

1. I strongly support the OP, I would not change a standard header file. I think there are several reasons.  For example, a future upgrade of the tool chain (which comes with a new set of headers) breaks an old app if it ever gets maintained. Or simply building the application on a different machine gives an error, merging two apparently correct applications may give an error, ... . Nothing good is likely to come of that. -100
2. Use `#define ...` to make the error go away. I do not like using macros to change standard libraries. This seems like the seeds of a long-term bad idea. If in future another part of the program uses another function with a similar problem, the application of the 'fix' gets worse. Some inexperienced developer might get the job of maintaining the code, and 'learns' wrapping strange pieces of `#define` trickery around `#include` is 'normal' practice. It becomes company 'practice' to wrap `#include <ctype.h>` in weird macro  workarounds, which remains years after it was fixed. -20
3. Use a command line compiler option to switch off inlining. If this works, and the semantics are correct, i.e. including the header and using the function in two source files does not lead to a multiple defined function, then okay. I would expect it leads to an error, but it is worth confirming as part of the bug report. It lays a frustrating trap for someone else, who comes along in the future. If a different `inline` standard library function is used, and for some reason a person has to look at the generated code it won't be included either. They might go a bit crazy wondering why inline is not honoured. I conjecture the reason they are looking at generated code is because performance is critical. In my experience, people would spend a lot of time looking at code, baffled before looking at the build script for a program which works. If suppressing inline is used as a fix, I do feel it is better to do it everywhere than for one file. At least the semantics are consistent and the high-level comment or documentation might get noticed. Anyone using the build scripts as a 'quick check' will get consistent behaviour which might cause them to look at the documentation. -1 (no-inline everywhere) -3 (no-inline on one file)
4. Use tolower in a bogus way in a second source file. This has the small benefit that the build system is not 'infected' with extra compiler options. Also it is a small file which will give the opportunity to explain the error being worked around. I do not like this much but I like it more than the fiddling with standard headers. My current concern is it might not work. It might include two copies which the linker can't resolve. I do like it is better than the weird 'take its address and see if the linker shuts up` (which I do think is an interesting way to test the edge cases). -2
5. Code your own tolower. I don't understand the wider context of the application. My reaction is *not* to code replacements for library functions because I am concerned about testing (and the unit tests which introduce even more code) and long term maintenance. I am even more nervous with character I/O because the application might need to become capable of handling a wider character set, for example UTF-8 encoding, and a user-defined tolower will tend to get out of synch. It does sound like a very specific application (debugging to a port), so I could cope. I don't like writing extra code to work around things which look like bugs, especially if it is commercial software. -5
6. Can you convert the error to a warning without losing all of the other checking? I still feel it is a bug in the toolchain, so I'd prefer it to be a warning, rather than silence so that there is a hook for the incident and some documentation, and there is less chance of another error creeping in. Otherwise go with switching off the error. +1 (Warning) 0 (Error)

Switching the error off seems to lose the 'corporate awareness' that (IMHO) IAR owes you an explanation, and longer term fix, but it seems much better than messing with the build system, writing macro-nastiness to futz with standard libraries, or writing your own code which increases your costs.

It may just be me, but I dislike writing code to work around a deficiency in a commercial product. It feels like this is where the vendor should be pleased to have the opportunity to justify its license cost. I remember Microsoft charged us for incidents, but if the problem was proven to be theirs, the incident and fix were free. The right thing to do seems to be give them a chance to earn the money. Products will have bugs, so silently working around it without giving them a chance to fix it seems less helpful too.

Comment: "MISRA" is not a linker, it's a set of rules for 'safe' embedded code.  The IAR toolchain can be configured to let you know when you're violating MISRA rules.

Comment: I understand what MISRA is. But the configuration/constraints imposed by the linker, which throws an Error (I can cope with warnings) seems to have a serious bug.  I have never used IARs tools, but a couple of friends say their tools are clunky but solid, so I had allowed that it might not be IAR's linker. But it might be something else triggering (what I think is) an error.

Comment: Taking the address at file scope within the RS232_Server translation unit didn't resolve the error. However, I added it to the main.c file and the link error went away. :-)

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - I assume that effect was similar to calling it in a bogus function, though maybe fractionally more benign because there is no machine instruction to call it. Interesting. Have you got the ability to "raise an incident" with IAR?

Comment: @gbulmer There is no bug. MISRA-C:2004 only allows C90, so it does not know about the inline keyword. In this case, inline is likely a compiler extension. If compiler and static analyzer were both IAR, their analyzer most likely knows about this compiler extension and ignores it. And we are then left with `int tolower(int _C)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you disable this particular MISRA check (you should be able to do that just for the `RS232_Server` translation unit) rather than use the one of the workarounds you suggest. In my opinion the utility of rule 8.10 is pretty minimal, and jumping through the kinds of hoops in the suggested workarounds seems more likely to introduce a higher risk than just disabling the rule. Keep in mind that the point of MISRA is to make C code less likely to have bugs.

Note that MISRA recognizes that "in some instances it may be necessary to deviate from the rules" and there is a documented "Deviation procedure" (section 4.3.2 in MISRA-C 2004).

If you won't or can't disable the rule for whatever reason, in my opinion you should probably just reimplement `tolower()`'s functionality in your own function, especially if you don't have to deal with locale support. It may also be worthwhile to open a support incident with IAR. You can prod them with rule 3.6 says that "All libraries used in production code shall be written to comply with [MISRA-C]".

Comment: +1 for 'You can prod them with rule 3.6 says that "All libraries used in production code shall be written to comply with [MISRA-C]".'

Comment: Update: I removed rule 8.10 for the RS232_Server translation unit and still get the link error. :-(

Comment: I am definitely going to submit an issue with IAR, quoting rule 3.6.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @Thomas: my mistake about disabling the rule for only the one compilation unit - since that rule deals with the behavior of global symbols and is implemented by the linker, I think you'll have to disable it for the whole project. Hopefully the linker will respect that setting.

Comment: @Michael Burr: I believe changing the setting for the whole project is a bad thing.  I was hoping that disabling it for the one compilation unit would resolve the error.  This keeps impacts to the smallest unit.  But since it didn't work, the other choice, to disable it for the entire project would defeat the quality object for the many. "The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few.'

Comment: Or maybe don't feed C99 code to a MISRA-C:2004 checker and there wouldn't be any problems. Stop blaming IAR.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **MISRA-C:2004 does not allow inline nor C99**. Upcoming MISRA 2012 will allow it. If you try to run C99 or non-standard code through a MISRA-C:2004 static analyser, all bets are off. The MISRA checker should give you an error for the inline keyword.

I believe a MISRA-C compliant version of the code would look like:

```
static uint8_t tolower(uint8_t ch)
{
  return (uint8_t)(isupper(ch) ? (uint8_t)((uint8_t)(ch + 'A') - 'a') : 
                                 ch);
}
```

Some comments on this: MISRA encourages `char` type for character literals, but at the same time warns against using the plain char type, as it has implementation-defined signedness. Therefore I use uint8_t instead. I believe it is plain dumb to assume that there exist ASCII tables with negative indices.

`(_C + ('A' - 'a'))` is most certainly not MISRA-compliant, as MISRA regards it, it contains two implicit type promotions. MISRA regards character literals as char, rather than int, like the C standard.

Also, you have to typecast to underlying type after each expression. And because the ?: operator contains implicit type promotions, you must typecast the result of it to underlying type as well.

Since this turned out to be quite an unreadable mess, the best idea is to forget all about ?: entirely and rewrite the function. At the same time we can get rid of the unnecessary reliance on signed calculations.

```
static uint8_t tolower (uint8_t ch)
{
  if(isupper(ch))
  {
    ch = (uint8_t)(ch - 'A');
    ch = (uint8_t)(ch + 'a');
  }
  return ch;
}
```

Comment: I think you make a good point about ensuring that the compiler is not in C99 mode and is configured to not permit extensions.  However, if IAR wants to advertise a MISRA compliant compiler, then there should be a MISRA compliant `tolower()` in `ctype.h` (granted, the compiler needs to be configured to use the MISRA compliant version - the requirements of that configuration should be documented by IAR somewhere).